# Create a column of initials from a column of names as a string in R

Tags: r

Here's an example df I want to extract the capital letters from:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c("Words are Here", "Okay", "Be Good Now", "WTF are you Doing", "it's good"))
```

When I use `str_extract_all(df$b, "[A-Z]", simplify = )` I get a list of all the caps
with simplify = TRUE:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "W"  "H"  ""   ""  
[2,] "O"  ""   ""   ""  
[3,] "B"  "G"  "N"  ""  
[4,] "W"  "T"  "F"  "D" 
[5,] ""   ""   ""   ""
```

or with simplify = FALSE:

```
[[1]]
[1] "W" "H"

[[2]]
[1] "O"

[[3]]
[1] "B" "G" "N"

[[4]]
[1] "W" "T" "F" "D"

[[5]]
character(0)
```

I don't know how to take either of these to get my desired output which is a vector like:

```
("WH", "O", "BGN", "WTFD", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `gsub` to match one or more characters that are not an upper case and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("[^A-Z]+", "", df$b)
#[1] "WH"   "O"    "BGN"  "WTFD" ""
```